# Agregar SUM(X) de variaas tablas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Mi problema es el siguiente
Tengo tres tabla una llamada
PTO_PRESUPUESTO,
V_EJE_CDP,
V_EJE_RP
Estoy tratando de agregar la sumatoria por Rubro(codigo) de V_EJE_CDP Y V_EJE_RP  a la tabla PTO_PRESUPUESTO,
Al momento de hacerlo con V_EJE_CDP me da los resultados esperados, cuando intento hacerle el SUM a V_EJE_RP la sumatoria de V_EJE_RP se altera, voy a colocar una imagen con los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me entiendan.

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Bienvenida Minerva Fuentes a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Para el código y datos, no pongas capturas de pantalla, edita tu pregunta ya agrega todo en forma de texto.